# Can I add in js reference to an online .d.ts file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, .d.ts

We have an js library that is online (pure javascript file), and we would like to add reference to .d.ts, so the user to able to use the .d.ts without downloading or installing anything. The goal is user to have Intellisence in VS Code for that library.

Comment: The user won't have to download the library itself, but seems that they will have to download the d.ts files..

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using [Triple-Slash](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) directive references.

Just add this line in top of your file.

```
/// <reference path="./path/to/myTypes.d.ts" />
```